# Whats wrong with the following code

Tags: c++

I have written down a code in C++ to make the words appear in array from a string input.
But it doesn't works due to overflow or something. Compiler doesn't show any error though.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
    char a[100];
    gets(a);
    char b[100][100];
    int I=0;
    for(int j=0;j<strlen(a);j++) //runs the loop for words
    {
        int k=0;
        do
        {
            b[I][k]=a[j];
            k++;            
        }
        while(a[j]!=' ');
        I++;
    }
    cout<<b[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Poor formatting.  Or something.

Comment: (When you ask a question about an error, describe the error as precisely as you can, copy/pasting error messages if at all possible)

Comment: Use `strncpy()` to transfer C-style strings! Preferably use `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>` instead!

Comment: Never use `gets`, even in C. There is no way to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: @g-makulik: you forgot a "never" there, as in "Never use `strncpy`!"

Comment: @MikeSeymour There is no `gets` function in modern C.  It was removed from C++11.

Comment: But how do I take input in characters then? If not gets, I can use cin but that gets cumbersome.

Comment: And of course, the only C++ here is the final output.  (And since it is of just one character, a compiler could replace all of the code after the `gets` with `std::cout << a[0];`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: For better or worse, it exists, albeit deprecated, in C99 and C++11. (I don't know about C11, since I haven't done much C this century; but I get the impression that many C programmers aren't that "modern").

Comment: @MikeSeymour My comment was somewhat facetious.  As you say, it exists, whatever the standard says.  And there's an awful lot of bad documentation and bad training material out there, which no doubt uses it (even though we knew enough not to use it as early as 1985).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to use C strings, you need to add a null terminator at the end of each string

```
do {
    b[I][k]=a[j];
    k++;
} while(j+k<strlen(a) && a[j+k]!=' ');
b[I][k] = '\0';
```

As ppeterka noted, you also need to change your loop exit condition to avoid an infinite loop.

Note also that the repeated calls to `strlen` here and in your code are wasteful.  You should consider calculating this once before your `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a[100];
    gets(a);
    char b[100][100];
    int I=0;
    int j =0;
    while(j< 100) //runs the loop for words
    {
        int k=0;
        do
        {
            b[I][k]=a[j+k];
            k++;

        } while(a[j+k]!=' ');
        b[I][k+1] = '/0';
        I++;
        j= j+k;
    }
    cout<<b[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```